# Calcular diferença de horas no AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho duas variáveis, `startTime` (01:00:00 AM) e `endTime` (02:00:00 AM), preciso calcular a diferença entre uma e outra, como faria isto no angular? vi que existe o `Date.parse()`, porem preciso passar uma data.

Comment: [http://momentjs.com/](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Exemplo co filter:

```
generalFilters.filter('dateDiff', function () {
  var magicNumber = (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
  return function (toDate, fromDate) {
    if(toDate && fromDate){
      var dayDiff = Math.floor((toDate - fromDate) / magicNumber);
      if (angular.isNumber(dayDiff)){
        return dayDiff + 1;
      }
    }
  };
});
```

```
{{entry.toStr | dateDiff:entry.fromStr}}
```

Créditos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635082/calculating-date-difference-with-angular-filter

Answer (score 1):

Veja se algum desses te ajuda no que você precisa:

1. simples:
   **http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/b60djmho/**
2. com intervalos:
   **http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/1cyxoytv/**